# How to center align circles?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I've got 4 circles, which have to be aligned to the center (vertically and horizontally). How can I ahieve this?

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk62zsxv/23/)

Here's my template:

```
<ion-content has-header="false">
   <div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
     <div class="row no-padding">
       <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
       <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
       <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
       <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.dashboard-grey-menu {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #959595;
}

.circle { 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  width: 10vw;
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}
```

**vertical-align: middle** and **text-align: center** properties won't work.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `flexbox` display type, you can easily achieve this:

```css
.dashboard-grey-menu {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #959595;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
  <div class="row no-padding">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="circle">Foobar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="circle">Foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="circle">Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="circle">Baz</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First we set the `.dashboard-grey-menu` to `display: flex;` and tell it to align the items in the center (both vertically and horizontally) using `justify-content`. Then we set the `display: flex;` on the `.row` element, and tell it to equally divide the space between the circles.

Comment: Maybe you could know the answer. What would I do if I wanted to insert some text inside the circle? Also on the middle.

Comment: @BillyLogan `flexbox` saves the day again. See my edit. :)

Comment: You make me wanna read a book about flexbox. Much appreciated!

Comment: col class is not used

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method. It's close but not 100% centered on the X axis. Better might be to use `flexbox` as you're already using it anyhow through the ionic framework.

```css
  .dashboard-grey-menu {
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: #959595;
    position: relative;
  }

  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 15vh;
    background-color: #B7B7B7;
    margin-left: 6vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
   <div class="row no-padding">
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your approach. I will consider it in the future.